# Does Russia have real-time encryption communication agreement with India?

Tags: united-states, russian-federation, india

I was reading [this article](https://www.upi.com/US-India-agree-on-defense-communications-cooperation-pact/9241536339271/) and I quote:

> [...] *It will give U.S. communication systems to India and allow real-time encrypted transmissions between compatible U.S. and Indian ships and aircraft.* [...]

This is, I believe, supposed to effectively drive the final nail into the coffin of Indo-Russian strategic relationship/partnership .

What does Russia think about this? What was Russian response thus far?

.

**Note.** Any Russian user in politics.SE would be appreciated if he could shed some light on this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Communications equipment has little to do with strategic partnership

India mostly buys Russian military equipment, French to a lesser extent, and lately some US and Israeli (and from few other countries, but is not that relevant) . There are various consideration with each purchase: quality/cost, political relations (especially considering Pakistan) , transfer of technology, strings attached (US often requires inspection of equipment they sold) etc ...

US and India could agree to share some data over compatible equipment, such transmissions are usually encrypted. It does not mean much for Russia, because they too certainly could communicate with Russian made equipment in Indian possession.

Real threat for Russia is the fact that they now have another competitor in Indian arms market, but this is hardly surprise. Russia was always aware that India could buy weapons from practically anyone (except China) , and they never deluded themselves that they have exclusive rights to that market. They just have to work harder and offer qualitative edge over their competitors. This is actually happening right now, as it look like [India will buy S-400 SAM system](https://www.oneindia.com/india/10-things-know-about-s-400-missiles-that-india-will-purchase-from-russia-2779302.html) from Russia.